# Insert to Postgres system table with specified OID

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is one way to populate system table:

```
create pg_proc 1255 bootstrap rowtype_oid 81
 (
 proname = name ,
 pronamespace = oid ,
...
insert OID = 1242 ( boolin 11 10 12 1 0 0 0 f f f t f i s 1 0 16 2275 _null_ _null_ _null_ _null_ _null_ boolin _null_ _null_ _null_ )
```

Is anyone aware of syntax which allows me to specify the value for OID column ?
This would be useful when populating system table in an upgrade scenario with rows that are used by feature in later release.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you quote is [BKI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bki.html) code and can only be executed from a C function during cluster initialization. That is intended to only be run during `initdb`, and I don't think it is safe to try to modify data in an existing catalog table with a custom backend process in `BootstrapProcessing` mode at a later time.

The only place where you could safely write such code is if you extend PostgreSQL and want to add your own catalog entries during `initdb`.

You don't say why you want to do that, but odds are that you are solving a problem in the wrong way, particularly if you want to write values with an object ID ≥ `FirstNormalObjectId`. Anything in PostgreSQL that depends on certain objects having a fixed object ID is doing the wrong thing (unless these are system objects created by `initdb`).

All that said, from PostgreSQL v12 on, the `oid` column is no longer a special system column, so you could modify a system catalog and add entries with a certain `oid` using normal DML statements. It is still no good idea to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.